# How can I retrieve dynamic added content using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My scenario is this:
When the page is loaded, a listbox with countries is loaded.

By selecting an item from a dropw down list, a country item in the listbox is selected using jQuery.

Now that a country is selected in the listbox, I call a function which retrieves cities and populate a city listbox.

The code looks something like this:

```
  $('#MyDropDownList').change(function() {
      (...) // Selected country is set here

      populateCityListBox();

      //this alert is undefined. Probably because it's triggered before the callback in populateCityListBox()
      alert(jQuery('#cityListBox option[value=Oslo]').val()); 
  });

  function populateCityListBox()
  {
    //Get ID for selected country
    var ctryID = jQuery("select#countryListBox").val();

    jQuery.post("wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery_bll.php", { instance: 'getCitiesByCountry', countryID: ctryID },
      function(data)
      {
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[i].city + '">' + data[i].city + '</option>';
          }
          jQuery("select#cityListBox").html(options);

          // This alerts the option text, which also is Oslo
          alert(jQuery('#cityListBox option[value=Oslo]').val()); 
      }, "json");
  }
```

My problem is this: I'm not able to retrieve values in the city listbox after I have run the function  `populateCityListBox();`. I **am** able to retrieve values in the $.post callback.

What can I do to be able to retrieve the values after the function is triggered? (I know it has to do something with some stuff being callback, while others run "realtime"... or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Since your request is **asynchronous**, the code keeps on running. You could potentially substitute something like so:

```
$('#MyDropDownList').change(function() {
      (...) // Selected country is set here

      populateCityListBox(function () {
          //this alert should work now
          alert(jQuery('#cityListBox option[value=Oslo]').val());
      });


  });

  function populateCityListBox(callback)
  {
    //Get ID for selected country
    var ctryID = jQuery("select#countryListBox").val();

    jQuery.post("wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/jquery_bll.php", { instance: 'getCitiesByCountry', countryID: ctryID },
      function(data)
      {
          var options = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' + data[i].city + '">' + data[i].city + '</option>';
          }
          jQuery("select#cityListBox").html(options);

          // This alerts the option text, which also is Oslo
          alert(jQuery('#cityListBox option[value=Oslo]').val());
          callback(); 
      }, "json");
  }
```

By placing `callback` as an argument of `populateCityListBox`, we are able to call that function inside of your `change` up there. In essence, it is just a 'modified' callback of sorts: we are just executing yet another function in the callback. This lets you run the function `populateCityListBox` independently in a console like you could and still be able to use the application logic or whatnot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: humm... I just get the err msg `callback is not defined`. I'm guessing I should replace 'callback(); with some other code?

Comment: That's.... odd. Scope has memory; it should have callback defined. Since `callback` is an argument on `populateCityListBox` and where we're calling `callback` is inside of that function (albeit in an anonymous one, but ah well) it should work. My only guess is that you've changed the logic of the app somehow and broken the code. 

My "simulation" works perfectly for me, so I am not sure what the problem is. Perhaps posting the updated code or something similar to that could be of use, assuming that you are at liberty to do that.

Comment: ok. I'm not quite there yet, but it gives me a good idea on how to fix it. So I'm accepting the answer. Thanks :)